# how to fix, error is "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component."

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make config() run but it somehow fails.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class try1 extends Component {

  constructor(noofVertices){
    super();
    this.noofVertices = this.noofVertices
    this.edge = {}
this.a = [];}


addVertex(v){
  this.edge[v] = {}
}

addEdge(v, w,weight){
  if (weight == undefined) {
           weight = 0;
       }
       this.edge[v][w] = weight;
  }

config(){

    var vertices = [ 'App0', 'App1', 'App2', 'App3', 'App4' ];

    // adding vertices
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      this.addVertex(vertices[i]);
    }

    // adding edges
    this.addEdge('App0', 'App1',1);
    this.addEdge('App0', 'App2',1);
    this.addEdge('App0', 'App3',1);
    this.addEdge('App0', 'App4',1);

    this.addEdge('App1', 'App0',1);
    this.addEdge('App1', 'App2',1);
    this.addEdge('App1', 'App3',1);
    this.addEdge('App1', 'App4',1);

    this.addEdge('App2', 'App0',1);
    this.addEdge('App2', 'App1',1);
    this.addEdge('App2', 'App3',1);
    this.addEdge('App2', 'App4',1);


    this.addEdge('App3', 'App0',1);
    this.addEdge('App3', 'App1',1);
    this.addEdge('App3', 'App2',1);
    this.addEdge('App3', 'App4',1);

    this.addEdge('App4', 'App0',1);
    this.addEdge('App4', 'App1',1);
    this.addEdge('App4', 'App2',1);
    this.addEdge('App4', 'App3',1);


    this.traverse('App1');
    } 



traverse(vertex)


 {

            for(var adj in this.edge[vertex])
                this.a.push(this.edge[vertex][adj])
        this.a.sort()


           //this.updateEdge1('App0');   
        }




render(){

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      this.config()
      <Text>{this.a}</Text>

    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

}
);
```

I am expecting 11111 to be displayed on screen.

It is showing error "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component."

I am trying to deal with graphs, I have tried maps also but that didn't work.

Does react native supports maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice your `this.a` property on your `try1` component is an array: `this.a = [];` and you're trying to display this property directly within your `render()` method like so:`<Text>{this.a}</Text>`. However, this causes issues since:

The `render()` method **doesn't support rendering a return type of just an array directly**. When you call a `React` component's `render()` method it must return one of the following:

1. **React elements**. Typically created **via JSX**. For example, `<div />` and `<MyComponent />` are React elements that instruct React to render a DOM node, or another user-defined component, respectively.
2. **Arrays and fragments**. Let you return multiple elements from render. See the documentation on fragments for more details.
3. **Portals**. Let you render children into a different DOM subtree. See the documentation on portals for more details.
4. **String and numbers.** These are rendered as text nodes in the DOM.
   Booleans or null. Render nothing. (Mostly exists to support return test && `<Child />` pattern, where test is boolean.)

For more information check out the `render()` [spec](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render).

There are **other error**s in this code as well:

1. *Custom react components must be named with an uppercase* otherwise JSX will think this is an HTML tag instead. Rename `try1` to `Try1`.
2. Move your config function call before the `return` statement as the return statement expects the **actual view itself to be returned**.

With these points in mind, try looping through `this.a` and giving each element in the array a `Text` element to be displayed, something like the following:

```
render() {
    this.config();
    let aEles = this.a;
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            aEles.map(edge => (
               <Text>{edge}</Text>
            ));
        </View>

    )  
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass function in return, it interprets it as a string value and View can't render text.

You can use lifecycle methods to execute this function.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render an array inside `<Text></Text>` component. You can only render pure string.

If you want to display dynamic text inside  component use "state". This may help you:

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 ...
 ...
 this.state = {
  a = []
 }
}
```

And then:

```
render() {

 this.config();

 return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        this.state.a && this.state.a.map(data=> (
           <Text>{data}</Text>
        ));
    </View>

 )  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.config() is a function that you write this in jsx.
if you want to call config function, you must write outside of jsx.
this.config() in return, consider as a string. every string must be inside  Text tag. so you see this error.

```
render(){
  this.config()
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{this.a}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some conditional statements then use **ternary operators**. If you are using **&&** and then passing a component after that then it will through you an error. See below what was my code. Here is **Feed** is my component:

> Before

```
{userId && <Feed posts = {posts}/> } // this will give you an error
```

> After

```
{userId ? <Feed posts = {posts}/> : null} // this works fine
```

So maybe you have such kind of problem with your code. Have a look now.